# autowired vaadin component gets index -1

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-spring-boot

I use vaadin-spring. I created `public abstract class AbstractBasicVerticalLayoutWithMenu extends HorizontalLayout implements View` and I have two normal classes extending it. In abstract class I `@Autowire` Menu component defined:

`@UIScope
@SpringComponent
public class Menu extends CssLayout`

both classes are annotated

`@UIScope
@SpringView`

I have very strange issue in one of views, that my menu component is not being displayed.

I did some digging and added logging. On

`@Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event)`

method I added logging and tried many thigs and I found that when I do  `this.getComponentIndex(menu)` that wrong view component has index -1!

Interesting thing is that if I remove correctly displayed view from navigator (i do it: `getNavigator().addView(FirstTesterView.VIEW_NAME, firstTesterView);`) then this incorrect view is back to correct.

I have no idea why, but it looks like only first of instantiated classes extending acstract gets @Autowired component but not next.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I suspect that you menu is a [singleton](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton) which is the default scope in spring. At the same time, a Vaadin component can have only one parent at any time, eg you can not include the same menu instance in 2 different views. So, just make it a [prototype](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) so you get a new instance each time. Otherwise please post more code or a [sscce](http://sscce.org) if possible

Comment: You are completely right. Please make answer from this comment to let me approve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index -1 means that the component was not found among the children.

Now, if your component is [singleton](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton), which is the [default scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) for a spring bean, then you always get the same instance. Furthermore, a Vaadin component can only have [one parent](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#setParent-com.vaadin.ui.HasComponents-) at any given time, so probably you've missed some `IllegalStateException` in the log.

To fix this, you can set the scope of your menu to [prototype](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) so you get a new instance each time.